# My custom tabs have disappeared

Tags: discussion, support, search

I had a custom tab set up to show me the list of most recently unanswered questions in a few fields I'm comfortable in. But now they're gone, presumably in relation to the meta thread where they were talking about shifting to 'version 3'.

How do you set this up in the new system? Has that feature been completely axed? If so, that's going to probably make a fair dint in how quickly new questions get handled (if at all) - does anyone else consider that a problem?